# MySQL: Retrieve results related to two id of users

Tags: mysql, sql

**EDIT: I know, my database isn't normalized, but I can't change it, thanks.**

I have a table called `user_dialogs` with `id, user_id, dialog_id, type, status, created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

I not found a good way to retrieve an existent `dialog_id` between `user_id 1` and `user_id 2` with `type='PRIVATE'`.

I try to use IN: `user_id IN(1,2) and type='PRIVATE'` but i get `dialog_id` that user 1 made with user 3 for example.

What is the best way to get the dialog_id just between user 1 and 2?

How to call this problem/algorithm? I don't know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. Your data, as you describe it, isn't normalized and as such there's no way to describe that relationship. You need to have a table that describes the actual relationship between a `user` and a `dialog` where the relationship is __many-to-many__ (_i.e. more than one user is involved in the same dialogue, and multiple users are involved in multiple dialogues_). This isn't possible when you stating the relationship between a dialogue and a user is __one-to-one__.

Comment: Is dialog_id not unique between two (or more)users who are conversing?

Comment: An user can be in a dialog just one time(unique by user), but a dialog can have many users.

Comment: So you're saying that more than two users can share the same `dialog_id`, but you only want to find the `dialog_id`s where those two specific `user_id`s were involved in the same `dialog`, basically?

Comment: Yes. I need to know if an user talked with an other specif user a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to find dialog_id's shared between user 1 and user 2 with type='PRIVATE' for both.

One solution is to search for all dialog_id's for the user 1 with type = 'PRIVATE', then search dialog_id's for user 2 with type = 'PRIVATE' which are in common with user 1

```
SELECT ud.dialog_id
FROM user_dialogs ud
WHERE type='PRIVATE'
AND user_id = 2
AND ud.dialog_id IN (
    SELECT dialog_id
    FROM user_dialogs
    WHERE type='PRIVATE'
    AND user_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    dialog_id
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as UserCount
    ,COUNT(*) as OccurenceCount
FROM
    user_dialogs
WHERE
    user_id IN (1,2)
    AND type = 'PRIVATE'
GROUP BY
    dialog_id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicitly, let's assume we have the following schema to describe this data in the 3rd normal form.

```
CREATE TABLE user (id int);
CREATE TABLE dialogue (id int);
CREATE TABLE user_dialogue (user_id int, dialogue_id int);
```

There are 3 tables. A `user` a `dialogue`, and the `user_dialogue` table which describes the many-to-many relationship between users and dialogues.

So given that we have 3 users, and 2 dialogues as you describe...

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES(1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO dialogue VALUES(1),(2);
INSERT INTO user_dialogue VALUES(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(3,2),(3,1);
```

One way to extract the dialgoues that occur between two specific users would require a query like this where we `JOIN` the table onto itself and `GROUP` by `user_id` then filter out only those results where either id is present using the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT d1.user_id, d1.dialogue_id
    FROM user_dialogue d1
    JOIN user_dialogue d2 ON d1.dialogue_id = d2.dialogue_id
    GROUP BY d1.user_id;
    HAVING user_id IN (1,2)
```

Giving us the desired result set...

```
|user_id | dialogue_id |
------------------------
| 1      | 1           |
| 2      | 1           |
```

Now you have an adjacency list of users and dialogues.